# Can "remote repository" mean two different things with Bitbucket?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-remote

I can login to my Bitbucket account and click "Create" to create a new *remote repository*. I can also create a remote repository using the `git remote add` command.

```
$ git remote add [Remote Repository name] [url of existing Remote Repository]
```

However, this seems to add a remote repository *to* a remote repository! I've read that `git remote add` actually adds an "alias" to the remote, but the terminology is still really confusing to me. Did they really give "remote repository" two separate definitions, or do I have something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are two very different things. The command

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

does not *create* a new repository; it merely declares the repository living at `<url>` as a *remote* of your local repository. In plain terms, that command tells your local repository the following:

> Be aware that there exists another repository, living at `<url>`, which you shall call `<name>`.

In contrast, when you click "Create repository" on Bitbucket, you are actually *creating* a brand new repository. That repository is "remote" in the sense that it doesn't live on your machine, but on one of Bitbucket's servers.

[image]

---

Your confusion about the terminology may stem from the fact that "remote" is a relative term, not an absolute one: repository is not *intrinsically* remote; it is only remote with respect to another repository/machine.

To add to your confusion, the term "remote" is also used, in some contexts, to refer to `<name>`, as opposed to the repo that lives at `<url>` itself.

Comment: Yes thank you for the clarification. I think part of the confusion is that it's common for that alias/connection object to be referred to as a "remote". People also will casually refer to the origin as a "repo"